# React Native FlatList does not load data after the initialNumToRender count exceeds

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working in react-native `0.72.7` version.
In `FlatList` on writing prop `initialNumToRender={50}`, upto 50 items in my `FlatList` are getting displayed, other than that are getting displayed, I have total 100+ items.

I have two projects with same react native version in **function component project, same `FlatList` code working properly(getting rendered for 100+ items)**, but when I try with class component project `FlatList` this issue occurs.

```
// Class component code     
// when I put this condition it's working, but `ListEmptyComponent` props is not working,

    
 if(this.props.data.length>0){
          <FlatList                
               initialNumToRender={50}                
               data={this.props.data} //in data i have 117 records but it's show only 50 records              
               renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderFlatlistItem(item, index)}
               ListEmptyComponent={
                   <EmptyComponent
                        colors={this.props.colors} 
                        emptyMessage={this.props.emptyMessage} />
                }
           />
    }
```

I also tried setting `initialNumToRender={this.props.data.length}`, this is working fine, but the problem is my application is getting crashed and its lagging

Comment: It should definitely not crash, but can you show us your ```renderFlatlistItem ```, maybe your ListItems way to complex?

Answer (score -1):

1. **`onEndReached` Not Triggered**:
   Ensure that `onEndReached` and `onEndReachedThreshold` props are properly set in your `FlatList`.
   `onEndReached` should be a function that fetches more data and updates the state accordingly.

```
     <FlatList
          data={yourData}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <YourItemComponent data={item} />}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          onEndReached={loadMoreData}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}/>
```

2. **State Update Issues**:
   Check if the state is being updated correctly when new data is fetched. Ensure that the newly fetched data is appended to the existing data in the state rather than replacing it entirely.
   Example (in the loadMoreData function):

```
    const loadMoreData = () => {
      // Fetch more data...
      // Update state to append new data to existing data
      setYourData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...newlyFetchedData]);
    };
```

3. **Data Availability**:
   Make sure there is more data available to fetch beyond the initial set. If the `FlatList` reaches the end without more data available, `onEndReached` won't trigger.
4. **Performance Considerations**:
   If the data being loaded is very large or if there's a performance bottleneck, the additional data might take longer to load, making it seem like the `FlatList` isn't fetching more data.
5. **Incorrect Implementation**:
   Double-check the implementation of `onEndReached` and related props to ensure they're set correctly.
   Review these points in your code and ensure that `onEndReached` is being triggered when you scroll to the end of the list and that new data is correctly appended to the existing data in the state. If the issue persists, sharing relevant code snippets could help in diagnosing the problem more accurately.

Comment: Parthik thank you for your answer. But my question is that same above code without passing  `onEndReached` working properly. in functional component code !